# ux: best way to emphasize or convince user to fill website recommended price and convince user to show interest

Tags: usability, website-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

We have recently started buying used vehicles from customers through our website. The form looks like:

[image: Form where user fills used car details]

As soon as user fills make, model, version, year, km information, we show him/her the price on which we can consider to buy this car. This we start showing as "$ 5000/- Recommended Price". Once user fills all the fields and click on save button, user is navigated to the next form which looks like:

[image: voucher to give final offer to the user]

If user clicks on "Help Me Sell My Car", we contact the user to finalize the deal.

Please note, this is not real form and I am not looking forward to font size change/image change etc. help. What i want to know:

1. Is there any better way to convey the user "Recommended Price". Should it be in placeholder as shown OR somewhere else?
2. The "Help Me Sell My Car" form that we show on step2, should we show that at Step1 itself OR step2 is better? If step1, what is the best way to display this kind of offer to the user?

Comment: You're saying that the system will spew out a recommended price? So if that's the case why is that an input field that the user can edit?

Comment: Also "help me sell my car" doesn't even look like a button.

Comment: @Majo0od: The recommended price is just a placeholder, once user focuses on price text field, this price goes away. These are not actual forms,  only the text and flow is final, we have not got the designs yet. So, the button, colors, fonts etc. would be taken care of.

Comment: How about showing them the field, and under it a button that says "show our recommended price" - when the user clicks the button, it is replaced by "Recommended Price: $5000" or whatever

Comment: but that adds an extra step for the user to view the recommended price, don't you think it should be shown upfront?

Comment: I agree with @tobybot. I would suggest the same. What you are implementing is like a calculator for the car's price. My question is, can the user change the recommended price??

Comment: the user can't change the recommended price but user put his expected price to sell car, this price would then override the recommended price

Comment: @sahil So, if I understand your process (not the layout) correctly, the answers to the main inputs determine your "recommended" price, and the user is then given an opportunity to override that with a minimum they would accept? If so, have the data-inputs first, followed by a non-editable display "Our recommended price is $xxxxx", followed by a final edit box along the lines of "Minimum asking price", where the user can enter an override (with help/hover/tool-tips etc. to tell the user that they only need to fill in a value if they don't like your recommendation).

Comment: user has to manually enter the price, even if it is same as "recommended price". User has to enter that in price text box. I didn't get your idea clearly, can you explain or show your idea in a simple form?

Comment: @sahil I'm saying that I think your "recommended price" (derived from the user's responses) might be better shown as a separate element (probably just above the field where they enter their chosen price) instead of being the "placeholder text" of the input box.

Answer (score 1):

I would show the automatic calculated price as text above the input field.

*Our offer for your car: **$5000***

Leave this in place when your user fills in their expected amount. This way it will stay on their mind longer and still visualy imprents them with your recommendation.

How about a radio button or checkbox ("*Accept our offer*") to have the user choose between the recommended price and filling in a different price? That saves them typing a price if they accept your offer and yet makes them confirm it.

And as for question 2, it depends on the amount of screens that follow. Let's say there are 3 screens, then show this pricing screen as 1 / 3, and the next as 2 / 3, etc. Make it clear that they are almost there. Use as few steps as possible.